# No obtengo la lista de archivos que tengo en una carpeta, kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions, filereader

Tengo un problema, estoy intentando hacer una especie de File Explorer pero solo de PDFs en una carpeta en especial (/data/user/0/{el nombre de mi paquete]/files). Esto es asi pq yo con mi app creo pdfs en dicha carpeta y luego necesito tener en un activity la lista de todos ellos, yo solo quiero sus paths para luego abrirlos en otra activity.

Primero me fije si podia contar cuantos archivos tenia dentro pero me da resultado 0:

```
val carpeta = File(filesDir.toString())
    println(filesDir.toString())
    val lista: Array<File> = carpeta.listFiles()
    println(lista)
    var cuenta = 0


    for (i in lista.indices) if (lista[i].isFile()) cuenta++
    println("\n Hay $cuenta archivos")
```

Para ver que pasaba puse un println() en mi val "lista" y me dio de valor `[Ljava.io.File;@4bcece8`.

No se si el error se debe a alguna cuestion de permisos, dentro de mi Manifest agregue:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Sobra decir que dentro de mi carpeta files si existen 3 pdfs.

Desde ya muchas gracias a cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Ahora también creo que debes pedir permiso sobre los archivos y carpetas que quieres abrir https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files o si quieres acceder a todos los archivos necesitas un permiso extra https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a lo que comentas:

> estoy intentando hacer una especie de File Explorer pero solo de PDFs
> en una carpeta en especial (`/data/user/0/{el nombre de mi paquete]/files`)

Lo primero que **debes revisar es la obtención de permisos, que deben realizarse manualmente, ya que no es suficiente agregar los permisos en `AndroidManifest.xml`**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Este es un ejemplo de como obtener el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` (Actualmente no es necesario pedir `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`), lo cual puedes realizar dentro del método `onCreate()` de tu activity principal.

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Permiso", "No se tiene permiso para leer.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Permiso", "Se tiene permiso para leer!");
    }
```